# How to use Like statement?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, continuous-integration

I meet an error like this:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'TANAH'%' AND a.id_bencana=b.id_bencana AND
>   a.id_daerah=c.id_kelurahan AND c.id_k' at line 1

```
SELECT a.tgl_kejadian,b.nama_bencana,a.alamat,c.nama_kelurahan,d.nama_kecamatan,a.kerugian,a.keterangan 
FROM data_kejadian a , data_bencana b, kelurahan c, kecamatan d 
WHERE b.nama_kejadian LIKE '%'TANAH'%' AND a.id_bencana=b.id_bencana 
AND a.id_daerah=c.id_kelurahan AND c.id_kecamatan=d.id_kecamatan AND a.tgl_kejadian 
BETWEEN '2019-12-03' AND '2020-01-10'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Learn to write queries cleanly!

- Use proper `JOIN` syntax.
- Use meaningful table aliases.

Your problem is misplaced quotes:

```
SELECT a.tgl_kejadian, b.nama_bencana, a.alamat, 
       k.nama_kelurahan, kc.nama_kecamatan, a.kerugian, a.keterangan 
FROM data_kejadian a JOIN
     data_bencana b
     ON a.id_bencana = b.id_bencana JOIN
     kelurahan k
     ON a.id_daerah = c.id_kelurahan JOIN
     kecamatan kc
     ON kc.id_kecamatan = k.id_kecamatan
WHERE b.nama_kejadian LIKE '%TANAH%' AND  
      a.tgl_kejadian BETWEEN '2019-12-03' AND '2020-01-10';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the quotation marks between `TANAH`.
Change it into this:

```
SELECT a.tgl_kejadian,b.nama_bencana,a.alamat,c.nama_kelurahan,d.nama_kecamatan,a.kerugian,a.keterangan 
FROM data_kejadian a , data_bencana b, kelurahan c, kecamatan d 
WHERE b.nama_kejadian LIKE '%TANAH%' AND a.id_bencana=b.id_bencana 
AND a.id_daerah=c.id_kelurahan AND c.id_kecamatan=d.id_kecamatan AND a.tgl_kejadian 
BETWEEN '2019-12-03' AND '2020-01-10'
```

To learn more about `LIKE` operator you can read it here: [SQL LIKE Operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)